# Adding WordPress Posts to Elementor Pro Form Select field

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have a client who wants me to create a field in the form where the customer can select additional products to add to their quote. The products are set up as posts. I am using a WordPress installation, with Elementor Pro and Dynamic ooo plugins, and I was able to create a call to collect all the post titles using:

Using the Elementor Pro using Dynamic ooo Token: [query:post] (as seen in the image)

**Here are the options in Elementor Pro Forms Module**

[image: Here are the options in Elementor Pro Forms Module]

**This is what the form looks like when you try to select an option**

[image: This is what the form looks like when you try to select an option]

The issue I am having is that it is bulking the post titles into one giant select item rather than single selection items separated by the post title. What I want to happen is that I can call all the post titles, and they will populate into separate the items into a multi-select where any of the post titles can be selected and added to their quote request. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Here is the link to see what I am doing:

http://www.closeout.gbwcompanies.com/product-closeouts/stone-veneer-closeouts/blue-ridge-matterhorn/

Click on the blue button to Request a Quote and the form popup should show you what I am talking about. You will see the select list on the first step of the form with all the post titles in one long item.

Here is a link to the Dynamic ooo docs that I used to get me this far:
[Dynamic ooo Docs for Tokens](https://help.dynamic.ooo/en/articles/4954060-tokens)

Edited:
Here is a code I am currently trying but is not working:

```
function get_posts_title_filter($data) {
global $post;
$args = array( 'cat' => 4 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$data = '<select select name="lstdate" id="prods" onchange="document.getElementById(\'prods\').value=this.value;"><option></option>';
foreach(  $data as $title ) {
    $output.=$title.'&#10;';
}

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
   $title = get_the_title();
   $output .= '<option value="'. $title .'">'. $title .' </option>';

endforeach;
$data .= "</select>";
return var_dump($data);
```

}

Comment: Solution for this problem is [query:posts|options] but html tag in option will look like this <option value="123"> title</option> where value is id of post. So, if this works for you ..

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the answer to my question. I am so sorry for not seeing this sooner. I found this article [Tokens Collection Link](https://www.dynamic.ooo/tokens-collection/insert-the-posts-list-on-a-field-select-form/)

If you are looking to do this, use the following shortcode:
[query:posts|options]

Answer (score 0):

i don't have the plugin. So i can test myself and give you final working solution. But from what i have after read the Dynamic ooo docs, this might be work:

1. open your theme's functions.php file.
2. insert this codes at very bottom (**above php close tag "?>" if have**) and save it:

   ```
   function get_posts_title_filter($data) {
   $output = '';  
      foreach ($data as $title) {
        $output .= $title.'&#10;';
      }
      return $output;  
   }
   ```
3. in your token setting, using this token:

   ```
   [query:post|get_posts_title]
   ```
4. if you get any error, send back to me for debug and correction.

Comment: No error, but it did not work, unfortunately. But I really appreciate your response. I might be able to work with this.

Comment: In that case, please **return var_dump($data);** instead of **return $output;** then send me the result.

Comment: The same situation, no error but it didn't work.

Comment: In that case, maybe i misunderstand the guides on docs. Please using this token: [query:post|get_posts_title_filter] in your token setting.

Comment: I did try that already. I probably should have said that. That caused a critical error that took my whole WordPress down. I can probably make a copy of the site and give you access if you would like?

Comment: Yes, that would be great. So i can quickly test, debug and give you working solution!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237408/discussion-between-nikimaria87-and-thng-nguyn).